# How to select MAX values from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have two different tables in sqlce database, and first one has a DateTime column named Date, and the second one has a DateTime column named Created...they show the dates of different events...now how can i find the date of latest event?(the MAX of both tables)

Comment: max of both datetime column row wise or the most recent of all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(combinedDate) FROM (
    SELECT MAX(Date) AS combinedDate FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(Created) AS combinedDate FROM Table2
)
```

Would something like this work?